# Does every iphone notification have to go through Apple

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I am evaluating using Mattermost for internal corporate chat.  This includes potentially using the [Mattermost Push Notifications Service](https://github.com/mattermost/mattermost-push-proxy)  to push notifications to corporate iPhones.  Mattermost says:

> For organizations who want to keep internal communications behind their firewall, this service encrypts notification messages with a private key under your control before sending them to Apple's public push notification service for delivery to your iOS devices.

Implementing a push notification service to push notifications to iPhones is new to me.  I have seen other posts about the [reliability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897575/apns-apple-push-notification-service-reliability) and [privacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23940555/does-the-apple-push-notification-service-represent-a-privacy-concern) of the APNS, but are there any options for sending notifications through a service that doesn't *have* to go through Apple?  If the answer is no, the implication is that all notifications for the 1B+ iPhones on the planet go through Apple...correct?  Again this is new to me so I am just trying to clarify my understanding of the overall architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be: Yes, every iphone notification have to go through Apple. At least the VoIP notifications.

From this discussion in Apple's developer forum regarding deprecating VoIP background registration vs. enforcing the use of PushKit:
[iOS 10 VoIP background mode no longer supported](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50106)

Question:

> How can we use an iOS 10 VoIP App (…) in closed internal networks (…) where no connetion to the internet is possible?

Answer from apple staff:

> There’s no supported way to do this.  To use CallKit you must link with the iOS 10 SDK, and if you link with the iOS 10 SDK you will not be able to use the legacy VoIP API.

IMO, this answer implies, that there is no self hosted private push service desinged into the apple push eco-system. Otherwise, the apple guy would have stated it here.